# how to validate below schema conditionally using Yup validation

Tags: node.js, validation, yup

How to validate below json schema with Yup validation,
data: {
"name": "tempName",
"age": 20,
"address": [
{
"addressLine": "street1"
},
{
"addressLine": "street2"
}
],
"proofOfdocs": [
{
"provider": "GAS",
"id": 1
},
{
"provider": "FUEL",
"id": 2
}
]
}

logic to be validated is
if array of json objects in proofOfDocs contain atleast one provider as 'GAS' then street1 as addressLine in array of json objects in address is not required else required

similar to this
if array of json objects in proofOfDocs contain atleast one provider as 'FUEL' then street2 as addressLine in array of json objects in address is not required else required

I have tried but couldn't succeeded